# 2002 4Runner - Smell of fuel by drivers side

Tags: toyota, fuel-system, smell, 4runner

I smell fuel off the drivers side wheel well of my 2002 4runner.

My check engine light is on and I changed my gas cap. The lights went out and back on. I think it's the connection.

It has a cover over the hose but how do I get the little brackets off without breaking them? It's got little round rivet like things?

This one has me me stumped.

Do I need to buy new ones or what?

Comment: Have you had the codes read? If so, what are they?

Comment: My brother did it but I don't remember he said it was the hose connection or the $400 sensor but most likely the hose. It reaks of fuel. He can't help me. I moved 2 hours away. The cover is something I've not done or seen. Nuts and bolts I'm good with. I don't want to pull them out and ruin them. What do I do? Thanks

Comment: Someone just told me they r plastic retainers and I have to buy them. Am having a friend pick them up. While in Phx. Will let u know how it goes. Or if I need to spend $400. Hope not!

Answer (score 1):

As the O2 sensor goes bad you can get a fuel smell without any leaks.  Have your car scanned at your local auto parts store.

This will give you any error codes for your vehicle malfunctions and can also tell you what the specific problem is and what parts(s) you may need to replace or repair.